# MySQL Query performance extremely depending on Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, innodb

I have a very strange problem with my MySQL (InnoDB) database and had hoped for some help.

In the query I essentially try to get (or rather count) the datapoints for a specific device depending on the MAC address of the device. All tables are rather small (max. 5000 entries) except the device_data table which has 14.7 million entries. We do have indexes on nearly fields in this table, definitely all that are used in the below query.

```
SELECT COUNT(DEVDATA.id) AS count FROM device DEV
        RIGHT JOIN device_data DEVDATA ON
        DEV.id = DEVDATA.device
        RIGHT JOIN device_ownership DEVOWN ON
        DEV.id  = DEVOWN.device
        INNER JOIN data_types DT ON DEVDATA.data_type = DT.id
        WHERE DEV.mac = '00000000000'
        AND DEVOWN.organisation IN (1,4,7,8,12,16,38,57)
```

My problem now is that when I execute this query for a device that has 18k data entries in the device_data table it'll take around 0.078 seconds (very fast) and run without problems. The EXPLAIN looks like this:

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys"                                    "key"            "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1"     "SIMPLE"        "DEV"           "const" "PRIMARY,mac,s_id"                         "mac"    "50"    "const" "1" 
"1"     "SIMPLE"        "DEVOWN"        "const" "Device_Ownership_Device_Unique,device"    "Device_Ownership_Device_Unique" "4" "const" "1" 
"1"     "SIMPLE"        "DEVDATA"       "ref"   "device_id,data_type"                       "device_id" "4" "const" "34208" "Using where"
"1"     "SIMPLE"        "DT"            "eq_ref"                                           "PRIMARY"    "PRIMARY"   "4" "device.DEVDATA.data_type"  "1" "Using index"
```

When I execute this for a device that has 60k entries in the device_data table (so only about three times as much) it'll take 144 seconds(!) and the EXPLAIN looks like this:

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table"    "type"   "possible_keys"                            "key" "key_len"  "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1"     "SIMPLE"        "DEV"      "const"  "PRIMARY,mac,s_id"                         "mac"    "50"    "const" "1" 
"1"     "SIMPLE"        "DEVOWN"   "const"  "Device_Ownership_Device_Unique,device"    "Device_Ownership_Device_Unique" "4"   "const"   "1" 
"1"     "SIMPLE"        "DT"       "index"  "PRIMARY"                                  "name"   "403"   "104"   "Using index"
"1"     "SIMPLE"        "DEVDATA"  "ref"    "device_id,data_type"                      "data_type"  "4" "device.DT.id"  "728"   "Using where"
```

As you can see the two top rows are the same but in the two bottoms there is definitely something completely different going on. So the only difference between those two queries is the MAC address I use to execute but the execution is vastly different.

If I am missing some crucial information please tell me and I'll try to add whatever is missing.

Thank you very much

Comment: Why all those RIGHT JOIN's? Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for the input. That probably just boils down to my (bad?) style of writing queries I suppose. However, do you think that this could have a performance impact?

Comment: I don't know MySQL that well to say. But perhaps basic INNER JOIN's will do fine here? Also, are all joined tables really needed? You know the data, I don't

Comment: @DesperateEi Outer joins do not allow for choosing join order in the optimizer, while inner joins (commutative and associative) give more freedom to optimizer, so yes, it may have significant performance impact. It might not be the case now, but you may want to try. As far as I can judge, join columns in "right" tables are foreign keys which essentially makes RIGHT JOIN logically (but not physically) equivalent to INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you for the information. Unfortunately in my specific case it didn't help with the issue (didn't impact performance). However, I was able to increase the performance by rewriting my query (see answer below). What I still don't understand though is, why the performance and even the EXPLAINs differt from another so significantly depending on my where condition. I would really want to know what kind of different behaviour happens under the hood in those two cases.

Comment: In general, optimizer may choose different plans depending on the estimated number of selected rows. E.g. if it knows that WHERE selects a single row, it will use Index Scan, but when the estimation of the result size is "nearly half a table" then Seq Scan is more preferable. Optimizer uses statistics about attribute values and sometimes when statistics data are wrong, it may take wrong decisions.

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you very much for that answer. This is what I needed to know and what is not so easy to find on the internet. Do you have any source for that so that I could read a little more on it?

Comment: @DesperateEi There is a number of good books on database internals. My personal favorite is "Database Systems: The Complete Book" by Ullman, Garcia-Molina, Widom
http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/dscb.html This paper might also be a good starting point: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/pods98-tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 0):

After doing further research and trying different solutions I was able to edit the query in a way that would lead to a consistent performance like in the first example. I essentially loaded the device data in its own subquery and only after that joined the data_types table to it, so that only the actualy datapoints would be joined. The query below diffes a little behaviour-wise from the original one, as I added some filtering and got the actual elements instead of a count but the general gist should be the same.

I still **DON'T know** what caused the behaviour (vast performance differences) in my initial question. If someone has an answer to that, please let me know.

```
SELECT DD.*, DT.name FROM (SELECT DEVDATA.* FROM device_data DEVDATA
LEFT JOIN device DEV ON DEV.id = DEVDATA.device
LEFT JOIN device_ownership DEVOWN ON DEV.id = DEVOWN.device
WHERE DEV.mac = '00000000000'
AND DEVOWN.organisation IN (1,4,7,8,12,16,38,57)
AND DEVDATA.data_type IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13)) DD
LEFT JOIN data_types DT ON DT.id = DD.data_type
WHERE (DT.NAME LIKE '%1%' OR DD.value LIKE '%1%')
LIMIT 0, 500
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being `NULL` so that it can exclude it from the count.  Is the `NULL` test needed?  The usual pattern is `COUNT(*)`.

Perhaps `JOIN` would give you the same result as `RIGHT JOIN`?

The joining happens before the `COUNT`; have you checked to see if the result is inflated.

It is not clear that you need `device_data and`data_types`; they lead to nowhere.

So, perhaps the query boils down to

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM  device d
    WHERE  d.mac = '00000000000'
      AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM device_ownership
                           WHERE device = d.id
                             AND  organisation IN (1,4,7,8,12,16,38,57) );
```

That needs these indexes:

```
device:  INDEX(mac)
device_ownership  INDEX(device, organization)
```

If you want to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.